# Como saber si se ha actualizado un registro desde mysqli

Tags: php

mi consulta es la siguiente, tengo un método que ejecuta consultas simples a la base de datos:

```
function ejecutarConsulta($sql)
    {
        global $conexion;
        $query = $conexion->query($sql);
        return $query;
    }
```

Donde la llamo desde el CRUD:

```
 public function editar($idcategoria, $nombre, $descripcion, $old_nombre, $old_descripcion) {
        $sql = "UPDATE categoria SET nombre='$nombre',descripcion='$descripcion'"
                . " WHERE idcategoria='$idcategoria' AND nombre='$old_nombre' AND descripcion='$old_descripcion'";   
        return ejecutarConsulta($sql);
    }
```

El return ejecutarConsulta($sql) me devuelve 1 aunque no haya actualizado la fila.
¿Ese 1 es el true de que pudo ejecutar la consulta?
¿Se puede saber si se actualizo el registro?

Desde ya muchas gracias por su tiempo.

Comment: Si utilizas MySQL puedes usar `mysqli_affected_rows`, con ello sabrás si tu consulta afecto o no alguna de las filas de tu tabla, te comparto el link de la documentación https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.affected-rows.php. Saludos.

Comment: Aparte de lo dicho por @JosueArriola, deberías considerar el uso de consultas preparadas. Tu código es muy inseguro y podrían atacar tu sistema borrando o robado datos. Para simplificar, podrías trasladar la ejecución de la consulta al método `editar`, porque esa estructura te va a fastidiar a la hora de implementar consultas preparadas. En `editar` tienes en contexto los datos que es lo que interesa, y desde allí puedes preparar la consulta, ejecutarla con toda seguridad y devolver un mensaje de lo ocurrido. Deberías también controlar errores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despues de ejecutar el query podes llamar a $mysqli->affected_rows para saber la cantidad de registros afectados.

```
    $query = $conexion->query($sql);
    if ($query){
       $afectados = mysqli_affected_rows($conexion);
       echo "Cantidad de filas afectadas: ".$afectados;
    }
```

Comment: Convendría devolver algún mensaje también en caso de error,  para no dejar al usuario en el limbo.